# which dates given week number, bash

Tags: bash, date, week-number

In Bourne shell, I need to know which dates belong to the same week. For example, week 16 in 2013 starts on April 22nd and ends on April 28th. Using the "date" command I can get the week number for a certain date but I need to go the other way around.

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15606900/11621 this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606567/unix-date-how-to-convert-week-number-to-a-date-range-mon-sun (and I have no more votes today).

Comment: You can use `cal`, that shows you the calendar of current month. Then `grep` and these kind of things.

Comment: Is this your question:  Given 2 integers, determine the dates contained in the specified week of the specified year.  The first integer is a 4 digit number corresponding to a calendar year (i.e. 1998), the second integer is between 1 and 52 and represents a week of the year.  Week 1 of a year would normally be a partial week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheap way to obtain week numbers - Use `ncal`, the week numbers are output below calendar

e.g.

```
ncal -w 4 2013
```

or

```
ncal -w 2013
```