# Get day of week of a specific week; Bash; Linux

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a week number in 2018, 38 for example.

And I need to get date of Monday for that week.. (it should be 17092018)

Really weird but I didn't find anything on StackOverflow for this (simple?) task.

Comment: See: [UNIX date: How to convert week number to a date range (Mon-Sun)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606567/3776858)

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just sad how I didn't see that already..