# Convert week number to date range in bash

Tags: bash, date

This has been asked multiple times over different forums, however, I didn't find the one working for me.

The best I could reach is the reply to this question: [UNIX date: How to convert week number to a date range (Mon-Sun)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606567/6770384)

```
function weekof()
{
    local week=$1 year=$2
    local week_num_of_Jan_1 week_day_of_Jan_1
    local first_Mon
    local date_fmt="+%a %b %d %Y"
    local mon sun

    week_num_of_Jan_1=$(date -d $year-01-01 +%W)
    week_day_of_Jan_1=$(date -d $year-01-01 +%u)

    if ((week_num_of_Jan_1)); then
        first_Mon=$year-01-01
    else
        first_Mon=$year-01-$((01 + (7 - week_day_of_Jan_1 + 1) ))
    fi

    mon=$(date -d "$first_Mon +$((week - 1)) week" "$date_fmt")
    sun=$(date -d "$first_Mon +$((week - 1)) week + 6 day" "$date_fmt")
    echo "\"$mon\" - \"$sun\""
}

weekof $1 $2
```

However, it is giving a date range of one week ahead. For e.g.; week number 20 and year 2020 should return date range from 11 to 17 May. But is giving 18 May to 24 May.

Please help.

Comment: 11-17 May is the 19th week of 2020

Comment: Week numbers may vary by region, [opochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020) shows `week 20` as `May 11 -  May 17`

Comment: I checked at http://www.whatweekisit.org/calendar-2020.html. It is showing 11-17 May is week 20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNIX date: How to convert week number to a date range (Mon-Sun)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606567/unix-date-how-to-convert-week-number-to-a-date-range-mon-sun)

Comment: This algorithm makes use of the fact that the first week of a year is numbered 00 and not 01. Hence your offset of 1

Comment: The script in my question is from the referred article only.